# На "ура" — нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

"Концерт прошел на ура" — берется ли в кавычки междометия "ура"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не берется. Междометие "ура" здесь выступает в роли существительного.